# Change permission mask on MariaDB PID file

Tags: permissions, centos, mariadb, pid, rhel

MariaDB by default starts and creates the PID file with `-rw-rw----`:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        6 Jul 18 11:38 localhost.localdomain.pid
```

I need to be able to read this PID file with another user. How can I change the permissions on this file to be created something like `-rw-rw-r--`? Remember this file is deleted once the DB is shut down and it is created on startup.

I have root permission and everything. I'm using the latest MariaDB version (10.1.14-1.el6) and RHEL 6 and SELinux is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

Add to the startup script:

```
$ umask 777
$ chmod 666 localhost.localdomain.pid
$ umask 770
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the "startup script". 

I ended up editing the _/etc/init.d/mysql_ script and added `chmod a+r $mysqld_pid_file_path` to the "start" section of the code.